# How do I create links to my tables in a password protected back end?

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I created an install for my database. However it loses the password for the linked tables to the back end.

I need to relink all the tables on load.

I found the below code to add specified table but I need to link all the tables in the back end DB and I don't want to repeat this code for every table.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strDbFile As String
Dim strLinkName As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strSourceTableName As String

strDbFile = "c:documents\mydb"
strPassword = "mypw"
strSourceTableName = "tblcaseid"
strLinkName = "link_to_caseid"

strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & _
    ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile
Debug.Print strConnect
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef
tdf.Connect = strConnect
tdf.SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
tdf.Name = strLinkName
db.TableDefs.Append tdf

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that i dont need to remove the table links and add them again just need to loop through the tables refreshing the link including the password in the strconnect

```
Sub relink()

Dim strDbFile As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strConnect As String

    strDbFile = "file location"
    strPassword = "database password"
    strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile

    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        ' ignore system and temp tables
        If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*" Or tdf.Name Like "exl*") Then
            tdf.Connect = strConnect
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

this worked